# selenium-side-runner is failing for Chrome, ran through fine with Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I'm trying out the command line runner of Selenium IDE `selenium-side-runner` on a .side file.

I can open this .side file in Selenium IDE and run the test suite, it can execute just fine, but when running the command line runner i get this error.

```
myuser@mycomputer [10:02:36] $ selenium-side-runner --debug selenium/seleniumtesting.side 
debug:   Could not load /Users/myuser/projects/selenium/.side.yml
debug:   { capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' },
  params: {},
  runId: 'a508a80619537b4ac9c18368857f84f2',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/',
  server: undefined,
  timeout: 15000,
  baseUrl: undefined }
info:    Running selenium/seleniumtesting.side
debug:   jest worker args
debug:    0=--no-watchman, 1=--testMatch, 2={**/***/*.test.js,**/***.test.js}
debug:   jest work opts
debug:    cwd=/Users/myuser/projects/selenium/side-suite-seleniumtesting, stdio=inherit
 FAIL  ./BasicFullCheckoutflow.test.js (6.314s)
  Basic Full Checkout flow
    ✕ 2. Add product to the cart (3035ms)
    ✓ 3. Checkout (1530ms)

  ● Basic Full Checkout flow › 2. Add product to the cart

    StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

      at Object.checkLegacyResponse (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
      at Executor.execute (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
```

UPDATE: This is only happening for chrome webdriver, when i run with firefox it went through fine

```
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox" selenium/seleniumtesting.side
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in headless mode with below options:-

```
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=chrome chromeOptions.args=[headless,no-sandbox,disable-dev-shm-usage]" selenium/seleniumtesting.side
```